# ifstream for breaking hashed strings

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream

Hi I want to read a txt file of hashed values using ifstream and to store the values in a array.

128 bit hashed string
Another 128 hashed string 
etc

Here's what I have so far:

```
string line;
ifstream myfile ("username.txt");
vector<string> data_arr;
int i = 0;

if (myfile.is_open())
    {
    while (myfile.good())
    {
        getline(myfile, line);          
        data_arr.push_back(line);
        i++;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }
else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

How can I make it so that I have each value of the array be 16 bytes long? I'm guessing that getline doesn't work for me since the hashed value could have the newline tag be part of the characters.

Anyway, I hope this makes sense, (probably not) since I'm typing this at 5AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If hashes are stores without newline symbols or spaces you can try something like this:

```
std::vector<char> hash(16);
myfile.read(&hash[0], 16);
data_arr.push_back(std::string(hash.begin(), hash.end());
```

You also need to check if reading was successful.